# Embedded JS in XML syntax highlighting

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to make syntax highlighting work with JavaScript code which is embedded into XML?

```
<file name="admin/view/template/sale/order_list.tpl">
    <operation>
      <search position="before"><![CDATA[<?php echo $footer; ?>]]></search>
      <add><![CDATA[        
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() {
    setOptions(); // on load
         ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```